# YouTube stream from video file

Tags: youtube, stream, video-streaming

is this possible to create live event by simply using video file instead of web camera? I don't see option like this in live event creation

Answer (score 0):

For doing this directly on youtube: No

For doing this by encoding some video file and push to youtube in real time: Yes

How to do?

Try wirecast play. Just like a live-feed console but free with some limit. Also  other rtmp server may work. One of them is `ffmpeg`. I tried before and can ensure it works. But it's a backend with only command line. For more functionality, you need a front-end app(you can stream/pipe to ffmpeg).

About ffmpeg rtmp read this:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtmp